# javax.jws.WebService : Could not generate specified XSD file

Tags: java, web-services, websphere

I have two EARs running on WebSphere.

In each one I have the same WebService, implemented as follows:

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;

@WebService(serviceName = "GestionXService")
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
@Component(value = "gestionXService")
public class GestionXService extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "searchClient")
    @WebResult(name = "ListCustomerEGBean")
    public CustomerEGBean searchClient(@WebParam(name = "nd") final String nd) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

In both web applications, the WSDL is generated correctly:

from `https://localhost:4443/webapp1/GestionXService?WSDL` 
and `https://localhost:4443/GestionXService?WSDL` and has the same contents.

But the problem is that I can't generate the XSD from one of the two webapps (the one with context `/`), it says:

> Error: Generic Error.
>
> Could not generate specified XSD file!

(In the other it works fine)

My question is:

- I'd like to put a break point somewhere and see what's happening when the XSD is being generated. Where should I put it?
- Where can I look for the differences between the two webapps? To see what prevents one of them from generating the XSD.
- Any other lead?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't put a breakpoint at the place where the XSD is being generated. From the code you quoted, it appears that you're relying on WebSphere generating the WSDL and XSDs for you; this kind of generation is done deep in WebSphere's core for which you don't have source-level access.
2. The only possible way for you to get a glimpse on what's wrong is to turn on JAX-WS tracing within WebSphere. Edit the server's trace settings and use `com.ibm.ws.websvcs.*=all` as a trace string. The JAX-WS traces often reveal the root cause for problems that you wouldn't see in the normal log files.

Comment: it still doesn't talk very much and no error is shown. I could find the xsd in `wstemp` (same contents for both applications), but still don't know why it can't serve it in one of them..

Comment: If no error is shown, use a more elaborate trace string: `com.ibm.ws.*=all`. One thing IBM is very good at is that they emit ridiculous amount of trace lines. You just have to find the right trace scope.

Comment: I activated all the logs, but it still says nothing about it :( But I just changed one of my applications context root from `/` to `/app1` and now it works.. (the other one was already `/app2`) Didn't know that was relevant.. But I still don't know why it doesn't work with `/`

Comment: Your original question showed as if each webapp is mapped to its own context root, and both of them were not `/`.

Comment: Yep it's actually `/` and `/app2`, didn't know it was relevant to the question .. sorry about that.

Comment: I just decompiled `com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet` and found that it has enough logs, but I can't find them anywhere (eclipse console, trace.log, SystemOut.log, ..). Do you know how to solve that ?

Comment: @MajidL that's very brave... no, I don't know. I would imagine it'd be `trace.log` if you enable the correct logging level.

Comment: Yep, I had to make a script to decompile handreds of thousands of classes.. anyway I'm still investigating but it seems to be closely liked to this http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK96567 (although we have a 7.0.0.23, and that issues is supposed to be fixed in 7.0.0.9)